# php and xajax call function to do change quantity action

Tags: php, xajax

previously i have posted one post about the cart page call shopcart.php but it seems that no one really can answer it. whenever i input new quantity and click change quantity button, it seems that the new amount cannot be got and the button has no action, (i really have tried really really hard to find the solution for three wks , uptil now still really cannot find a solution of where the problem is) hope everyone can give me a warm hand to find the problem for me or hints to me

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);
  session_start();
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  include_once('../../xajax_core/xajax.inc.php');  // 引用 xajax
  $xajax = new xajax();            // 建立 xajax 物件

  // 註冊回應函式　
  $chaObj=$xajax->registerFunction('change_quantity');
  $chaObj->useSingleQuote();
  $chaObj->addParameter(XAJAX_FORM_VALUES,'form1');
  $xajax->processRequest();        // 處理回應

  $xajax->printJavascript();


  //---------------------- 自訂函式區 ---------------------
  // 負責更改商品數量的回應函式

  function change_quantity($form) {

    $objResponse = new xajaxResponse();  // 建立回應物件
    // 表單中的 Checkbox 屬性為 p_id, 若有勾選, 其值才會傳入
    // 所以檢查表單欄位中有 'p_id' 資料, 表示使用者有勾選產品
    // 此時才做後續處理

    if(isset($form['p_id'])) {
      // 逐筆處理每一個被勾選的產品
      foreach($form['p_id'] as $p_id) {
        // 根據產品的訂購數量決定處理方式
        if($form['qua'][$p_id]=='0') {
          // 若訂購數量被設為 0, 則將此產品從購物車中移除
          unset($_SESSION['cart'][$p_id]);

          if(count($_SESSION['cart'])==0) {  // 若購物車變成空的
            $objResponse->                   // 則關閉視窗
              script('alert("cart has no items");window.close();');
              unset($_SESSION['cart']);
          }
          else  { // 若購物車中還有其它商品
            // 將被刪除的產品從網頁中移除
            $objResponse->remove($p_id);

            // 更新購物車中的金額總計
            $objResponse->assign('total','innerHTML',gettotal());
          }
        }
        else if ($form['qua'][$p_id]>0) {
          // 若設為大於 0 的值, 則將之設為購物車中的新數量
          $_SESSION['cart'][$p_id]['quantity'] = $form['qua'][$p_id];

          // 因已修改數量, 所以要更新購物車中的小計及總計金額
          $objResponse->assign('sub[' . $p_id . ']', 'innerHTML',
                               $_SESSION['cart'][$p_id]['quantity'] *
                               $_SESSION['cart'][$p_id]['price']);
          $objResponse->assign('total','innerHTML',gettotal());
        }
        else {
          // 若被設為負值, 則將之回復原本的值
          $objResponse->assign('qua[' . $pid . ']', 'innerHTML',
                               $_SESSION[$pid]['quantity']);
        }
      }
    }
    return $objResponse;          // 傳回回應物件
  } // 回應函式 change_quantity() 結束

  // 計算總金額的函式
  function getTotal() {
    $total = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $p_id => $item)
      $total += ($item['quantity'] * $item['price']);

    return $total;
  }


  //---------------------- 購物車 HTML  ---------------------
  // 目前購物車中有商品, 程式才取出購物車內產品並顯示於網頁
  if( !isset($_SESSION['cart']) ) { // 使用者尚未購物
    echo "<script>alert(\"you haven't chosen any products\");" .
         "window.close();</script>";
    exit();
  }
?>
<title>購物車內容</title>


<!-- -------------------- 用戶端 JavaScript ------------------ -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// 勾選或取消產品清單中所有產品 checkbox 的函式
function select_all(formName, elementName, selectAllName) {
  elem = document.forms[formName].elements[elementName];
  if(!elem) // 若找不到元素
    return;
  else if(elem.length!= null) // 若網頁列出多個產品 (elem 是陣列)
    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
      elem[i].checked =
        document.forms[formName].elements[selectAllName].checked;
  else
    elem.checked =
        document.forms[formName].elements[selectAllName].checked;
}

// 將勾選的產品之訂購數量設為0, 再產生非同步要求
function settozero(formName, elementName) {

  elem = document.forms[formName].elements[elementName];
  if(!elem) // 若找不到元素
    return;
  else if(elem.length!= null) { // 若網頁列出多個產品 (elem 是陣列)
    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
      if(elem[i].checked) {
        var qua =
            document.getElementById("qua[" + elem[i].value + "]");
        var subtotal = document.getElementById("sub[" + elem[i].value + "]");


        qua.value = 0;  // 將數量設為 0
        subtotal.value = 0;


      }
  }
  else {
    var qua = document.getElementById("qua[" + elem.value + "]");
    var subtotal = document.getElementById("sub[" + elem.value + "]");


    qua.value = 0;  // 將數量設為 0
    subtotal.value = 0;

  }
  var total_value = document.getElementById("total");
  total_value.value = 0;
  <?php $chaObj->printScript(); // 輸出呼叫回應函式的程式碼 ?>
}
</script>
<?php $xajax->printJavaScript('/'); ?>


<!-- ------------------- 購物車表單及表頭 -------------------  -->
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="../module.css" />
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="checkout.php">
<table width="800" border="0" align="center"
       cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"
       style="text-align:center;border:1px solid silver">
  <tr><th colspan="7">cart</th></tr>
  <tr style="background-color:silver;color:white">
    <td height="23" width="80">all
        <!----- 呼叫函式選取或取消全部的 checkbox ----->
        <input type="checkbox" name="all"
               onClick="select_all('form1','p_id[]',this.name);">
    </td>
    <td height="23" width="460">product name</td>
    <td height="23" width="60">unit price</td>
    <td width="10" height="23"></td>
    <td height="23" width="60">quantity</td>
    <td width="10" height="23"></td>
    <td width="70" height="23">subtotal</td>
  </tr>


<!-- -------------------- 輸出購物車內容 --------------------  -->
<?php
  // 呈現購物車表格內容
  $total = 0;
  foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $p_id => $item) {
    // 將此列的 id 屬性設為 $p_id, 以方便移除產品
    echo "<tr id='$p_id'>\n";
    echo "<td width='80' height='21'>" .
         "<input type='checkbox' name='p_id[]' value='" .
         $p_id . "'></td>\n";
    echo "<td>" . $item['name'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "<td width='60' >" . $item['price'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "<td width='10' style='border-width:0'>×</td>\n";
    echo "<td width='60'>" .
         "<input type='text' name='qua[$p_id]' id='qua[$p_id]'
         value='" . $item['quantity'] . "' size='3'></td>";
    echo "<td width='10' style='border-width:0'>=</td>\n";
    echo "<td width='70' align='right'>" ."<input type='text' size='6' id='sub[$p_id]' value='".($item['quantity'] * $item['price'])."' disabled>"."</td></tr>\n";
  }
?>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="6">total:</td>
    <td align="right" style="border-top:1px solid silver;width:70">
        <input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo gettotal(); // display total amount ?>" id="total">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<!-- -------------------- cart button --------------------  -->
<table width="800" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td height="23" align="center">
        <input type="button" name="DEL" value="remove products"
               onClick="settozero('form1','p_id[]')">
    </td>
    <td height="23" align="center">
      <input type="button" name="UPD" value="change quantity"
             onClick="xajax_change_quantity(xajax.getFormValues('form1'))">
    </td>
    <td height="23" align="right">
        <input type="button" name="CONT" value="continue shopping"
               onClick="window.close();">
    </td>
    <td height="23" align="right">
        <input type="button" name="CONT" value="checkout"
               onClick="location.href='checkout.php';">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: It's hard to answer a question with non-English comments and a huge chunk of code.

Comment: hi do you have skype name? so that i can send u my source for you to have a look

Comment: I would just use Pastebin and translate the comments into English, if you have the effort.

Answer (score 0):

isn't "innerHTML"... because tag id="total" is element form input,
correct is "value"

```
$objResponse->assign('total','innerHTML',gettotal());
```

correct...

```
$objResponse->assign('total','value',gettotal());
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?